# rolling mean with python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I want to write a rolling mean  code of m_tax using Python 2.7 pandas to analysis the time series data from the web page (http://owww.met.hu/eghajlat/eghajlati_adatsorok/bp/Navig/202_EN.htm).

```
   datum  m_ta m_tax     m_taxd m_tan     m_tand
------- ----- ----- ---------- ----- ----------
1901-01  -4.7   5.0 1901-01-23 -12.2 1901-01-10
1901-02  -2.1   3.5 1901-02-06  -7.9 1901-02-15
1901-03   5.8  13.5 1901-03-20   0.6 1901-03-01
1901-04  11.6  18.2 1901-04-10   7.4 1901-04-23
1901-05  16.8  22.5 1901-05-31  12.2 1901-05-05
1901-06  21.0  24.8 1901-06-03  14.6 1901-06-17
1901-07  22.4  27.4 1901-07-30  16.9 1901-07-04
1901-08  20.7  25.9 1901-08-01  14.7 1901-08-29
....
```

Here I tried my code as:

```
 pd.rolling_mean(df.resample("1M", fill_method="ffill"), window=60,   min_periods=1, center=True).mean()
```

and I got result:

```
m_ta            11.029173
m_tax           17.104283
m_tan            4.848637
month            6.499500
monthly_mean    11.030405
monthly_std      1.836159
m_tax%           0.083348
m_tan%           0.023627
dtype: float64
```

In another way I tried as:

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000), index=pd.date_range('1/1/1900',   periods=1000))
s = s.cumsum()
r = s.rolling(window=60)
r.mean()
```

and I got result

```
1900-01-01          NaN
1900-01-02          NaN
1900-01-03          NaN
1900-01-04          NaN
1900-01-05          NaN
1900-01-06          NaN
1900-01-07          NaN
1900-01-08          NaN
...
```

So I am confused here. Which one should I use?  Could someone please give me idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with version 0.18.0, both `rolling()` and `resample()` are methods that behave similarly to `groupby()` and are deprecated as functions.

[What's new in pandas version 0.18.0](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#window-functions)

[rolling()/expanding() in pandas version 0.18.0](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#window-functions)

[resample() in pandas version 0.18.0](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#resampling)

I can't tell exactly what your desired results are, but maybe something like this is what you want?  (And you can see the warning message below, although I'm not sure what triggers it here.)

```
>>> df

            m_ta  m_tax      m_taxd  m_tan      m_tand
datum                                                 
1901-01-01  -4.7    5.0  1901-01-23  -12.2  1901-01-10
1901-02-01  -2.1    3.5  1901-02-06   -7.9  1901-02-15
1901-03-01   5.8   13.5  1901-03-20    0.6  1901-03-01
1901-04-01  11.6   18.2  1901-04-10    7.4  1901-04-23
1901-05-01  16.8   22.5  1901-05-31   12.2  1901-05-05
1901-06-01  21.0   24.8  1901-06-03   14.6  1901-06-17
1901-07-01  22.4   27.4  1901-07-30   16.9  1901-07-04
1901-08-01  20.7   25.9  1901-08-01   14.7  1901-08-29

>>> df.resample("1M").rolling(3,center=True,min_periods=1).mean()

/Users/john/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:1: FutureWarning: .resample() is now a deferred operation
use .resample(...).mean() instead of .resample(...)
  if __name__ == '__main__':

                 m_ta      m_tax      m_tan
datum                                      
1901-01-31  -3.400000   4.250000 -10.050000
1901-02-28  -0.333333   7.333333  -6.500000
1901-03-31   5.100000  11.733333   0.033333
1901-04-30  11.400000  18.066667   6.733333
1901-05-31  16.466667  21.833333  11.400000
1901-06-30  20.066667  24.900000  14.566667
1901-07-31  21.366667  26.033333  15.400000
1901-08-31  21.550000  26.650000  15.800000
```